# How to create data grid with user inputs using drop down method in Visual studio code 2022 community version using ASP.NET core web app(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, datagridview

I was working on web application where we need to create drop down menu which redirects to data grids/Tables in the dropdown menu. In the data grid user should be able to input their data in the grid in same page. User can able to add or delete columns.